# How does Chrome hide "GIF" button from Gboard on its search view?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, searchview, gboard, android-chrome

I am looking for an elegant solution to block gif/emoji input from Gboard on Android. Since I use 
 `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`, there is no trivial way of leveraging `onCreateInputConnection` to create a custom `AppCompatEditText`. However I happened to find that Gboard doesn't show a gif button at all from Chrome's search view.

Is there an `API` or `input type` to achieve this?
Note: `voice search` is enabled here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please use the below in your editText:

eyourEditText.setPrivateImeOptions("disableGifKeyboard=true;");